# How to update a bcrypt password in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, bcrypt

So i have this router where when the admin adds a new staff the password gets hashed it works perfectly fine in the add/staff route but when the admin tries to update the password the password does not get hash anymore plus when that user login with that new password it always says password incorrect(obviously which I have define) can someone please help me?

```
//Adding the staff which works perfectly fine   
router.post(
      "/add/staff",
      passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
      (req, res) => {
        if (req.user.isAdmin === true) {
          const newUser = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            role: req.body.role,
            password: req.body.password
          });
          if (req.body.adminCode === "admin123") {
            newUser.isAdmin = true;
          }
          bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
              if (err) {
                res.json({ success: false, msg: "Failed to add user" });
              } else {
                newUser.password = hash;
                newUser
                  .save()
                  .then(user => {
                    res.json({ success: true, msg: "User added" });
                  })
                  .catch(ex => {
                    return res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
                  });
              }
            });
          });
        } else {
          return res.json("Acess denied");
        }
      }
    );



//The update route which does not hash the password 
    router.put(
  "/update/:id",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    if (req.user.isAdmin === true) {
      User.update(
        { _id: req.params.id },
        {
          name: req.body.name,
          email: req.body.email,
          role: req.body.role,
          password: req.body.password,
          password2: req.body.password2
        }
      )
        .then(success => res.json({ msg: "Updated Successfully" }))
        .catch(err => res.json(err));
    }
  }
);
```

And also I am using passport and jwt

```
const JwtStrategy = require("passport-jwt").Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require("passport-jwt").ExtractJwt;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = mongoose.model("users");
const keys = require("./dbSecretKeys");

let opts = {};
// opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("jwt");
opts.secretOrKey = keys.secretOrKey;

module.exports = passport => {
  passport.use(
    new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
      User.findById(jwt_payload.id)
        .then(user => {
          if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
          }
          return done(null, false);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    })
  );
};
```

This is the one that I have tried

```
router.put(
  "/update/:id",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    if (req.user.isAdmin === true) {
      User.updateOne(
        { _id: req.params.id },
        {
          name: req.body.name,
          email: req.body.email,
          role: req.body.role,
          password: req.body.password
        }
      )
        .then(userUpdateData => {
          bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            bcrypt.hash(userUpdateData.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
              if (err) {
                res.json({ success: false, msg: "Failed to update user" });
              } else {
                userUpdateData.password = hash;
                userUpdateData
                  .save()
                  .then(user => {
                    res.json({ success: true, msg: "User updated" });
                  })
                  .catch(ex => {
                    return res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
                  });
              }
            });
          });
        })
        .catch(err => res.json(err));
    } else {
      return res.json("Access Denied");
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: You need to hash the password upon update as well. Do not store the user's password in plain text!

Comment: @JoeClay can you have a look again at my updated question